# Include "resource.h" in Windows C++ project

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi

Sorry for a perhaps very beginners question. I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit). I am studying how to build (a very simple) Windows application. I created a menu resource with ID `IDR_MENU1`, but when I tried to load it, I get `Error   C2065   'IDR_MENU1': undeclared identifier` compiler error.

By including the full path of `resource.h` in the manner below, everything works:

```
#include "C:/full_path_to_resource_h/resource.h"
```

The question is, is it meant to be done this way, or am I missing some project or IDE setting. Even though, I have a solution that works already, I want to learn best practices.

Comment: yes, you need `#include "resource.h"` (usually you not need set full path )

Comment: @john, corrected. (Both errors were there, now the post refers to correct one).

Comment: @RbMm thanks, I tried with <resource.h>, which didn't work, but it works with "resource.h"

Comment: `#include <resource.h>` tells it to look in the compiler system paths first then look in your folders. That won't help you.

Comment: ***Error   C2065   'IDR_MENU1': undeclared identifier compiler error.*** Look at the `resource.h` file.. Maybe you have more than 1 of them and there is one in the same folder as your project while the second one is at `C:/full_path_to_resource_h/resource.h`

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to check the architecture of the project created by **Windows Desktop Application** template. For a Windows application named *WindowsProject3*, *WindowsProject3* header which is included in *WindowsProject3* source would include *resource.h*.

It's convenient to edit *WindowsProject3.rc* in Visual Studio Resource View.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I strongly recommend using **CMake**, even on Windows. With **CMake** you can easily specify where to get you includes from. There are plenty of tutorials out there and **CMake** is a standardized tool that makes cross-platform applications easier to manage. Might be an additional tool to learn but it´s worth it! Also you are not depending on the project files by Visual Studio anymore and can in theory use **VS Code** and compile there with the **MSVC** compiler

Comment: This does nothing to address the question being asked.

Comment: @IInspectable it does. With CMake, you have control over how you want to include you files. If you familiarize with CMake then you can decide how to include your headers. You can use [include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include_directories.html#include-directories) and [target_include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html) to make the directory of the header known while controlling its visibility.

Comment: You don't need CMake to place a common header file that's used by the C++ compiler and resource compiler *anywhere* in your source tree and reference it using a source tree-relative include directive. Are you confident that you understood the question that's being asked? Or are you just promoting CMake, regardless of whether it provides any value in any given scenario?